# custom module admin value not get right value at front end magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have created one custom module, but from backend, I can not get that proper value at the front end,

I don't understand what I do a mistake here, please guide me on this.

here is my code,

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="ncode" translate="label" sortOrder="11">
            <label>NCode Technologies</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="gsttax" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>nGST TAX</label>
            <tab>ncode</tab>
            <resource>Ncode_GSTtax::gsttax_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                
                    <field id="enablesngsttax" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>GST TAX Enable</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[Select Yes to enable GST TAX  module]]></comment>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>  

                    <field id="gstin" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>GSTIN</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[Enter the GST Number]]></comment>
                        <validate>required-entry</validate> 
                        <depends>
                            <field id="enablesngsttax">1</field>
                        </depends> 
                    </field>

                     <field id="gstrate" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>GST Rate(Percentage)</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[Set GST Percentage Which Your Products Fall.]]></comment>
                         <source_model>Ncode\GSTtax\Model\Label\Source\Rate</source_model>
                        <depends>
                            <field id="enablesngsttax">1</field>
                        </depends>
                    </field>  


                    <field id="gstminamount" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Minimum Amount of Product</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[Enter the Minimum Product Amount to Apply GST Rates.]]></comment>
                        <validate>required-entry</validate> 
                        <depends>
                            <field id="enablesngsttax">1</field>
                        </depends> 
                    </field>

                    <field id="gstbusssinesorigin" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Busssines Origin</label>
                        <comment><![CDATA[Enter the Origin Status]]></comment>
                        <validate>required-entry</validate> 
                        <depends>
                            <field id="enablesngsttax">1</field>
                        </depends> 
                    </field>
                             
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Block/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ncode\GSTtax\Block;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Data
    */
    protected $_postFactory;
    protected $_dataHelper;
    /**
      * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
      * @param \Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Data $dataHelper
      * @param array $data
    */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Data $postFactory, 
        \Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Data $dataHelper, 
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function gstEnable()
    {
      return $this->_dataHelper->isModuleEnabled();
    }
    
    public function getPostCollection(){
        $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
        return $post->getCollection();
    }
     public function helperInit() {
        return $this->_dataHelper;
    }
}
```

**Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ncode\GSTtax\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{    
    const MODULE_ENABLE                     = "gsttax/general/enablesngsttax"; 
    const XML_PATH_GST_IN                   = 'gsttax/general/gstin';
    const XML_PATH_GST_AMOUNT               = 'gsttax/general/gstminamount';
    const XML_PATH_GST_ORIGIN               = 'gsttax/general/gstbusssinesorigin';

    public function getDefaultConfig($path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    }

    public function isModuleEnabled()
    {
       return (bool) $this->getDefaultConfig(self::MODULE_ENABLE);
    }

    public function gst_in()
    {
       return (bool) $this->getDefaultConfig(self::XML_PATH_GST_IN);
    }

    public function gst_amount()
    {
       return (bool) $this->getDefaultConfig(self::XML_PATH_GST_AMOUNT);
    }

    public function gst_origin()
    {
       return (bool) $this->getDefaultConfig(self::XML_PATH_GST_ORIGIN);
    }

}
```

**view/frontend/templates/onepage/gsttaxview.phtml**

```
<?php
    $helper        = $this->helperInit();
    $gstin         = $helper->gst_in();
    $gstamount     = $helper->gst_amount();
    $gstorigin     = $helper->gst_origin();
    
?>

<?php  if ($block->gstEnable()): ?>
    <?php echo $gstin; ?>
    <?php echo $gstamount; ?>
    <?php echo $gstorigin; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**My OUTPU is like

> 1 1 1

**
**and I have entered below image data**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you're using 'default' scope when getting config values. In this case, you will be getting the values defined in your etc/config.xml file. In order to get the actual configured value, you need to use 'store' scope.

So in your code you should replace

```
return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
```

with

```
return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: i have tried this but its not work

Comment: Have you flushed cache after adding the changes?

Comment: Ah, I got it! In your methods gst_in(), gst_amount(), etc. you have '(bool)' in each 'return' statement. You should remove this. Because it will convert all the values to boolean.

Comment: yes you are right..its work now thanks

Comment: Please, don't forget marking the answer as the correct one ;) Thanks!